# MySql insert from one table to another where a field not null

Tags: mysql

i have a table "phonebook" which has 1.5M records,
some of the records have the "phonenumber" field empty.

i want to copy all the records that the "phonenumber" field is not empty into another table.
even due it seems really simple, i cant get it to work.

here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO phonebook2 (company,zip,city,address,tags,phonetype,phonearea,phonenumber)
SELECT company,zip,city,address,tags,phonetype,phonearea,phonenumber
FROM phonebook WHERE phonenumber != null && phonenumber != "";
```

i dont get any error,
but i get "0 rows affected".
in a manual search over the records, i do see NULL values for phonenumber.

any suggestions ?

** i have tried running the same query without the WHERE part and it does transfer all the records as it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `IS NOT NULL` instead of `!= null`.

*Source: [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)*

Comment: i am trying this atm, it takes some time since there are so many records.
can you explain why using IS NOT NULL is diffrent from != null ?

Comment: cool, this has worked, waiting 3 minuets now to mark it as answer.

Comment: Because != is for comparing values, while a NULL field doesn't have a value. See the linked manual page.

Answer (score 2):

Use IS NOT NULL instead of != null

Answer (score 1):

Another option is instead of IS NOT NULL use

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT phonenumber
FROM  phonebook)
```